# Avoiding accidentally creating a second account at "Or log in with your existing social profile"

Tags: login

User visits wordpress.com/log-in and sees

"Or log in with your existing social profile:"

User thinks "Well I'll just click that. How simple!"

However if the user already has a Wordpress account that is *not*
linked, this will just create an *additional* account!

One really cannot blame the user. He can't remember exactly which sites
he has already linked to which accounts.

Anyway he now realizes he has created an additional account and starts
to take steps to clean up his mistake.

Back on his original account, on
https://wordpress.com/me/security/social-login
when he tries to link it he will see

"This social account is already associated with a WordPress.com
account."

He now needs to log back in to the new account via the same social login
link.

Now in wordpress.com/me/security/social-login
he needs to disconnect the social account.

Now he needs to login via username and password to his original account,
(carefully avoiding the "Or log in with your existing social profile:")
and in wordpress.com/me/security/social-login
link his social account, so the problem won't occur in the future.

Also there is still the problem of deleting the second account... not an easy task...

My question is: can we really blame the user here?

Even if "existing social profile" was reworded "existing
linked social profile" that wouldn't stop the problem.

Comment: I don't quite follow if you just have an issue with how _wordpress com_ does it ? Or you are exploring how to implement a similar solution in self hosted WP site? It sounds more UX than WP development question in this form.

Comment: WP Help responded that 'There's no way to delete WordPress.com account completely.' Therefore all I can say is user beware.